# Validate Livewire public property against existing table in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a column named 'workorder_number' which is unique by default. I am adding a feature allowing my dispatchers to clone an existing work order and all its properties(cloning works if I hard-code a unique work order value).

Within the work order view, I added a single input form with a public property called 'new_workorder_number'. When I try to validate the value against the 'workorders' model, I get the error `No property found for validation: [447747]` *447744 is the 'new_workorder_number' value I entered.

How can I validate a public property that is not a column in the database to an existing column?

**edit.php**

```
...
public $new_workorder_number;

public function cloneWorkorder($id)
{
    $this->validate([
        $this->new_workorder_number => 'required|unique:workorders|min:4',
    ]);
...
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
...
<form wire:submit.prevent="cloneWorkorder({{$workorder->id}})" method="PUT">
    <div class="mb-4">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2">
          <div class="col-span-1">
            <input id="new_workorder_number"
                   wire:model.defer="new_workorder_number"
                   placeholder="New Work Order Number">
          </div>
          <div class="col-span-1">
            <button type="submit">
                Clone
            </button>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
...
```

Comment: You need to validate against `'new_workorder_number'`, not `$this->new_workorder_number`, which makes it look for the value as the field name.

Comment: @aynber I changed to `'new_workorder_number' => 'required|unique:workorders|min:4',` and got the error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'new_workorder_number' in 'where clause'`

Comment: It's hard to tell if that's for the lookup or for the insertion. If it's for the lookup, you'll need to add the column name to the unique clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using your validation wrong. Validating in Livewire is basically the same as in Laravel. If you change your validation as following, it should work:

```php
$this->validate([
    'new_workorder_number' => 'required|unique:workorders,id|min:4',
]);
```

I changed 2 things:

- Changed the key, since that is the property that needs to be validated on the Livewire component (hence the "no property found exception").
- Changed your unique validation rule to specify which column the unique should check, as how it's described in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-unique). When you check the source code for the unique validation (`Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes::validateUnique`) you will see that when you don't pass a second parameter, it will guess based on implicit attributes and otherwise returns the attribute, which is the key you're validating. Since you don't have the column `new_workdorder_number` on your table, it will throw an unknown column exception.